# Why when I join all the particles it destroys my model?

Tags: particles

I try to join the converted particles, but the result is a mess. Where do I miss something?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happened/have you done between screenshots 2 and 3?

Comment: check whether you applied rotation/scale....

Comment: Blunder,  between 2 and 3 I have selected some sugar cylinder and joined them, and the result explode my model. (I made the same thing with all the 754 object selected with the same result)

Comment: Chris I don’t understand your point?

Answer (score 2):

It's because the converted particles are separate objects but they all share the same mesh data (multi-user objects). It's similar to linked objects. You cannot edit the mesh nor you can apply *Location*, *Scale*, etc.

So before you can join them all into one object you have to make them single-user objects. **Select them all, then use menu *Object > Relations > Make Single Object > Object & Data***. After this, you can join them (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>). You will end up with one object that has one mesh that has as many loose parts as you had particles before.

If you have a look at the statistics you will see that this increases the verts count and face count.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it is very clear and effective! And it works now!
Thank you agan ;-)